# cancancan not authorizing controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, cancancan

I have a namespaced post controller with a discard function. I have set the ability class such that discard can only be done by owner of post if the post saved attribute is false.

```
class User::PostsController < User::BaseController
  authorize_resource :class => 'Post' 


  .
  .
  .
  def discard

    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully discarded.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end

  end
end



class UserAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can [:discard], User::Post, :user => user
    cannot [:discard], User::Post, :saved => true
  end
end
```

But the post can be discarded even when the saved attribute is true. But inside the views,

```
if can? :discard, @post
  <some action>
end
```

is working as expected. I think it is happening because cancan is authorizing only the model and not the controller actions. Is there any way to make it authorize controller actions?
PS: I use mongoid.

Comment: This is just a sample method. All controller actions are not getting authorized.

Comment: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions this will hepl you

Comment: @uzaif Thanks. i have tried it already and it works. But is there a better way than to manually authorize all the actions inside the controller?

Comment: why you need alternative way?

Comment: @uzaif what i'm doing now is authorizing each and every method inside all the controllers. instead is there a way to authorize the entire controller with a one liner?

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top of your controller file will authorize every controller action